# Update binded datagridview

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I bind data in my datagridview in a following way:
in my  program I have a global object Obmiary, which I pass to my form.

```
private ClassObmiary obmiary;
private BindingSource bs;
private BindingList<ClassObmiar> bList;

public FormObmiar(ClassObmiary Obmiary)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    obmiary = Obmiary;


    bs = new BindingSource();
    bList = new BindingList<ClassObmiar>(obmiary.Obmiary);

    // Fill bList with ClassObmiar

    bs.DataSource = bList;
    dgvObmiar.DataSource = bs;
 }
```

The  problem is when I change my global object somewhere else in the code, this dgv does not show changes. How to properly update this datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `bs.ResetBindings(true);`

or

`bs.ResetBindings(false);`

wherever you need to update the data.